# Azure deployment hanging in Eclipse

Tags: java, azure, azure-web-app-service

I previously did not have any issues with this, as I have been deploying Azure web app from Eclipse with no issue.  Usually it takes a few minutes, but currently it is taking forever with no real progress from what I can tell.  I have tried restarting Eclipse as well as deleting the Azure app and recreating a new one.  None of those work.  Are there some settings I need to reset ?

EDIT: Yes it is a Web App created in Azure, and I previously had no trouble deploying at regular intervals.  Last time however I wanted to abort the deployment and attempted to do so in Eclipse but it kept running and it seemed to be hanging so I shut down Eclipse and tried to deploy again but instead of taking just a few minutes, now it is stuck at the beginning with no progress.

I then decided to delete the web app, create a new one, and deploy to the new web app from Eclipse, but it is still the same with no progress.

EDIT: Adding Screenshots of the general environment and Azure configuration.

[image: config]

[image: choosing subscription]

[image: deploying]

Comment: it seems to be stuck at the very beginning saying "Uploading application"

Comment: You'll really need to provide more info than that. Otherwise, you'd only get wild guesses. Please edit your question accordingly, before this question is closed as "unclear" or "too broad."

Comment: Hello David, I updated with more info, hopefully this is more clear..let me know what info I might be leaving out.  I did try restarting the web app from Azure as well but that did not help.

Comment: First: no need to keep adding 'thanks' and no need to add my name to your question. Second: you still haven't shared any details: No screenshots of the deployment creation or the deployment in-progress (but hanging), or any web app config, or anything. You've only mentioned that you try to deploy and it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi David the thanks was left over from before I'll try to get some screenshots

Comment: @user6219373 Any eclipse logs or azure toolkit logs which show what happened when fail to deployed? Per my experience, I think some configuration or workspace metadata had been broken when aborted a deployment or forced exit eclipse, so I suggested that you can try to create a new workspace to create a new Azure WebApp to deploy on Eclipse. Any update after trying, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Hi Peter, it seems after waiting awhile when I tried to redeploy, it was able to successfully...i guess maybe on the Azure end it needed to timeout probably?

Comment: @user6219373 I'm agree with your guess. Maybe Azure WebApp waits timeout to recover or reset for the failed deployment connection. Maybe you can directly resolve it via restart the Azure WebApp instance. Thanks for your sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Just summarize for the above comments, the issue seems that Azure WebApp waits timeout to recover or reset for a failed deployment connection, so a suggestion is that trying to restart the Azure WebApp to recover or reset all status of the current instance fastly, or wait awhile then try to reconnect again.

But for some similar cases, if the above action failed, it's necessary for considering some metadata files in the current workspace, a valid way may be to create a new workspace to try to reconnect.

Comment: Hi Peter, lately I've been having to deploy my Eclipse projects to Azure multiple times in order for them to "show up".  Eclipse deploys succesfully but then when trying to reach the URL, I see HTTP 404 errors instead.  Only after multiple tries to deploy (all succesful) then I can finally reach the URL.

What happened this time was that I was trying to deploy multiple times again and this time received a message:

    FTP client can't store the artifact, reply code: 550

A few questions for your input: 
1.  Why do I have to deploy so many times ?
2.  How to overcome the 550 error?